# My VSCode Dart(Flutter) Intellisense have some problem

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

[image]

I  want to get List class's functions(methods) recommendation when I press Ctrl + Space(Windows).

But VSCode doesn't give me a recommendation, and it give me a default recommendation(Code Snippet).

It work well about a weeks ago. But after I press some button which shows bottom-right, This situation is occurred.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: The first obvious solution would be to reinstall the Flutter Tools for VS Code. Did you try that already?

Comment: @Heikkisorsa Yes, I reinstall Dart and Flutter Extension but I couldn't succeed.

Comment: There's an official discord channel for Flutter Tools for VS Code support. Try getting help there: https://discord.com/invite/xSTPEqm